# Trying to do wget or curl on page with user-password credentials

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to simulate a click on a "Export to HTML" button on a website by bash code on my terminal, but always get "sign-in.html" (the website is Etherpad, I want to get my notes by loop, too much pages... but have problems with credentials)... I tried everything (curl to get cookies, wget with credentials, curl with cookies on --post-data...) but cannot get into the page to click button on... what it's the best way to do that with BASH?

Regards

Examples:

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt "http://link/ep/pad/export/mysubject/latest?format=html" && wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies "http://link/ep/pad/export/mysubject/latest?format=html" -O subject/subject1.html
wget --user='MYSUER' --password='MYPASS' http://link/ep/pad/export/subject/latest?format=html
```